# Three.js : SVGRenderer?

Tags: svg, three.js

I've browsed the source of three.js and I haven't seen any file related to SVG. 
I've only found CanvasRenderer and WebGLRenderer. 
So what about SVG ? I thought it was supported.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `SVGRenderer` is not part of the library -- it is part of the examples.
   `SVGRenderer` can be found in the `examples/js/renderers/` directory.
2. If you are rendering with `WebGLRenderer`, use `SVGLoader` to load `.svg` files. `SVGLoader` is located in the `examples/js/loaders/` directory.
3. For demos, see https://threejs.org/examples/?q=svg

three.js r.99